# Dockerizing Mean Stack App on cloud instance and accessing it on browser

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, mean-stack

I have Dockerized a MEAN app on EC2 instance and trying to access the application(FrontEnd) on browser. I have linked three services i.e. FrontEnd, BackEnd and Database with the help of this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  angular:
    build: ./FrontEndYb
    ports:
      - "8085:4200"
    links:
      - app
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: ./BackEndYb
    ports:
      - "3011:3011"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I am able to call my node api viz "VM-IP":3011/api/users with the help of Postman to store data into mongo container. I am calling the BackEnd api in my FrontEnd code as follow
FrontEndYb/src/app/form.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FormService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }
saveInfo(firstname: string, lastname: string) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           this.httpClient.post('http://app:3011/api/users', {
          //here 'app' is  the name of node service written in docker-compose
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname
        }, { headers: headers }
).subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }
}
```

Also, my BackEnd/startup/routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const users = require('../routes/users')

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(express.json())
    app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    next();        
});
    app.use('/api/users', users);
}
```

The problem is, when I access the application on my browser and send some data from there, it gives this error

> """Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://app:3011/api/users' from origin
>   'http://54.169.178.148:8085' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is
>   not allowed for a preflight request.
>
> core.js:7187 ERROR  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
>   0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://app:3011/api/users", ok:
>   false, …} error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable:
>   false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …} headers: HttpHeaders
>   {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)} message:
>   "Http failure response for http://app:3011/api/users: 0 Unknown Error"
>   name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 0 statusText: "Unknown
>   Error" url: "http://app:3011/api/users"
>   **proto**: HttpResponseBase"""

In the above error 54.169.178.148 is my VM public IP

If I go inside FrontEnd container and call node container api viz http://app:3011/api/users, where 'app' is the name of node service as written in docker-compose.yml, it works fine.
I know that instead of using this.http.post('http://app:3011/api/users',..), if I use the public IP of my VM i.e. this.http.post('http://VM-Public-IP/api/users',...) in my FrontEnd code, it works fine, there is no CORS issue, status 200.

When I access my app in browser, the url 'app:3011/api/users' does not exists because now it is in external world(outside of VM), then what is the best practice to call node api in such cases.

This is the github url for reference to full code if needed github.com/tarunchawla28/mean-docker

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to call the url using the `EC2` dns name  not with the IP

Comment: anyway you can try to point  the name `app` to `EC2` IP address using the `hosts` file

Comment: If I point to EC2 ip instead of app, it works but then there will be no need to mention angular service in docker-compose.yml. Even if i separately run angular application also, it will work this way. So what is the use of writing angular services in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Same error after using EC2 dns name in browser for accessing the application.

Comment: what is FE name ? How to access frontend first ? what's output when you access http://privateip:8085 ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have API gateway or domain name pointing to you public ip of the vm.

Comment: This will work, but then, what is the use of writing angular service in docker-compose.. This can be done by running angular application separately and node plus mongo in docker-compose..